# How to detect if the user reached the end of the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have some entries , 20 for example

I load them 10 by 10 - I already programmed the pagination

my problem now , how to detect when the user reached to the last entry ?

my entries is rendered inside Content component which exist inside [the native-base library](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Components)

I tried this code - but not worked

```
<Content onEndReached={() => {
   console.log("fired"); // keeps firing
}}>
```

Comment: Please include the code you have written so far in the question.

Comment: @Tholle , I included it

Answer (score 2):

Just in case the native-base lib support props `onScroll` in component, I think my code can help you

> I'm using `SectionList` from `React Native` that supported [onScroll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) props

here's the example :

```
{...import}

const isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
  return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
    contentSize.height;
};

export default class foo extends...{
  <YourComponent
    onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
      if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
        if(!this.state.fetching_status){
          //what you want to do when the screen reached end of screen
          //console.log or something usefull
        }
      }
    }}
  />
}
```